# UK stamp in my US passport is illegible; how can it be clarified?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps

I'm a US citizen and I am visiting the UK. My passport stamp is illegible, although it says "you have __ months leave to remain in the UK" - the number is completely illegible. I am aware I'm allowed 6 months, but I need this to be clearly stamped in my passport. Where I should go, or whom should I contact to get this verified?  Thanks guys![image]

Comment: "I imagine I need this to be clearly stamped in my passport for various reasons" **imagine** being the operative word. UK Border Agency has your entry in the UK on their little shiny computers. Whether the stamp is legible or not, it doesn't matter much. They'll know when you came in and how long you stayed.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the stamp? I've only seen two kinds of visitor stamps, the one where the stamp itself says 6 months and the one where the stay is handwritten, but neither of those has exactly the text you put in quotes.

Comment: P.S. @dda is correct, the stamp is for your benefit and no one else will care about it. I haven't gotten one for several years now ([UK Registered Traveller](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller)) and the only one who is the least bit perturbed by that is me since I have to remember when they expect me to leave on my own; they already know. Knowing when they expect you to leave is the only important bit.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis - no i didn't type my question verbatim as written on the stamp . I do actually want to have it there - Let me see if i can attach an image, sure. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry not sure how to paste an image here. If you would want the exact wording i can't tell you that cos i can't read it, the stamp was not inked properly .  Happy to message a photo of it, but can't seem to paste it here. Thanks.

Comment: @Woolensheepie - you can't add an image here in the comments. You need to edit your question and then click the 'Image' button on the toolbar.

Comment: If you explain about why this is so important, perhaps someone can recommend an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

This is a  "Leave-to-Enter" stamp, serving as your non-visa national [Entry Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_certificate) ([Immigration Act 1971](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/77)). It is not a "Leave to Remain" stamp because those are used for something else.

The absence of handwriting on the stamp indicates that the leave-to-enter is 6 months ([Paragraph 23A of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk#pt1leavetoenter)).

> Where I should go, or whom should I contact to get this verified?

There is no need to read the blurred text in light of the rules cited above. But there are several paths you can pursue anyway...

If you are already inside the UK, you can take your passport to a [Citizens Advice Bureau](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/) and ask for a [Level 3 Adviser](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/office-of-the-immigration-services-commissioner).  Many CAB's have at least one such person, and they will be able to take your enquiry further if they cannot answer it on the spot.

If you are outside of the UK, you can submit a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration).

Or you can ask the Immigration Officer at your next landing interview.

---

**TL;DR**

As you are currently in the UK, you can safely assume that your leave-to-enter will expire at midnight 21 Jan 2018.

Comment: Every time I count 6 months forward from July (on my fingers) I end up in January.

Comment: @Dorothy wow!!!! Thank you so much that's what I need to know. Super informative and thank u so much for the links!!!

Comment: @Dennis of course you're correct; sorry...

Comment: @Dorothy I'm just curios how did you know all of that?

Answer (score 3):

That is a standard UK admission stamp for a tourist, [here is a slightly clearer image of one that Google found](http://www.ukstudentlife.com/Prepare/Visa/TouristVisa.jpg). It says you can stay for six months, or until 21 Jan 2018 given their definition of "six months".